# use transaction for persist objects into array with typeorm

Tags: typeorm

I have a electron app and I would like to insert a fixtures datas into my SQLite database. For manage data I use the typeorm library which bring the transactionnal functionality for isolate each object persistance.

When I use a loop into array of objects for create a transaction I have this strange error (for each object in 2 separate type) :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

I don't have any field that name is 'all'

code :

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data))
{
    console.log(key)
    console.log(value)

    await typeorm.getManager().transaction(transactionalEntityManager =>
    {

    })
}
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack, or a better description of wait you do inside your transaction? I'm afraid we can't help you much with so little data.

Comment: It seems that the content of my transaction is not very necessary (the error seems to be here with or without content). But I want to create a new entity object and immediatly persisted this)